# java jersay multiple ServletContainer Filters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jersey, servlet-filters

I have a filter configuration like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Jersey Web Application</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>/(images|js|styles|(WEB-INF/jsp))/.*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>pl.psnc.dl.wf4ever</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>pl.psnc.dl.wf4ever.auth.SecurityFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Jersey Web Application</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I would like to keep this filter

```
<param-value>pl.psnc.dl.wf4ever.auth.SecurityFilter</param-value>
```

but I need to add also next filter very similar to this one. How can I define to use next fitler lets say

```
 <param-value>pl.psnc.dl.wf4ever.auth.SecurityFilterAdmin</param-value>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Jersey API](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html#PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS), you may specify multiple filter classes delimited by `;`, `,` or space.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>foo.Bar;foo.Baz</param-value>
</init-param>
```